# I have a problem getting my sidebar responsive

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, responsive, sidebar

I created this sidebar with reactjs and with a certain fixed number of px for each element this caused the sidebar to not be reponsive. Unfortunately I'm not that good at CSS. Can someone help me transform this code to reponsive please ?
thanks in advance :)

**code is here**

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-dream-sp6he)

Comment: Hi, there is something wrong with your code example structure. I get an error when running the app.

Comment: sorry now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width in your sidebar.css instead of max-height.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```